# Which lumber to use to rip my own molding?

Tags: trim, lumber

I need to rip some custom sized molding on my table saw.  Which is the best kind of lumber to use?  I imagine plain 1x [Spruce-pine-fir (SPF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spruce-pine-fir) is not the best choice.

Comment: Poplar is a good choice

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the Pacific Northwest, Hemlock is the wood of choice for soft-wood molding. Pine would have to be clear (knot-free) and fine-grain Douglas Fir is expensive and tougher on the shaper blades.